# do loop error in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new at VBA so I'm sure I'm missing something easy... I am getting a compile error "Loop without Do"

The function being called GrabDataFromMinutes I have tested successfully on it's own. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
Public Sub CopyAllData()

Dim Location As String
Location = ActiveCell.Address
Dim CellValue As String
CellValue = ActiveCell.Value

Do
    If IsEmpty(CellValue) = True Then 'If cell is empty skip row'
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=-1).Activate
        Loop

If Location <> "C350" Then 'run the command unless EOF'
        Application.Run ("GrabDataFromMinutes")
        MsgBox "I got here"
        Location = ActiveCell.Address
        Loop

    End If

Exit Do

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to switch the end if and loop.  You cannot end the if  outside the loop if it is started inside the loop.  also delete the exit do.

Comment: Do you just want to go one row down? right now your code would go 1 row down and one column over

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by Scott you need to place the LOOP statement in the respective place. [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx)

Your code should be like this

```
Public Sub CopyAllData()

Dim Location As String
Location = ActiveCell.Address
Dim CellValue As String
CellValue = ActiveCell.Value

Do
    If IsEmpty(CellValue) = True Then 'If cell is empty skip row'
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=-1).Activate

    If Location <> "C350" Then 'run the command unless EOF'
        Application.Run ("GrabDataFromMinutes")
        MsgBox "I got here"
        Location = ActiveCell.Address

    End If

  End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the end solution to my own problem. The information provided by other answers contributed to fixing my problems. Thanks Everyone!

```
Public Sub CopyAllData()
'Declarations'
Dim CellValue As String
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer

Application.Run ("CopyMinuteHeaders") 'Copy Headers and setup sheet'

'Initialize values'
CellValue = ActiveCell.Value
CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRow = LastRow + 1

Do While LastRow <> CurrentRow

        If CurrentRow >= LastRow Then
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If CellValue = "" Then 'If cell is empty skip row'
        Do While CellValue = "" 'Skip multiple rows that are empty'
            ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Activate
            CellValue = ActiveCell.Value
            Loop

        End If

        If CurrentRow <> LastRow Then
        Application.Run ("GrabDataFromMinutes")
        CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
        CellValue = ActiveCell.Value
        End If

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `GrabDataFromMinutes` macro does, I would assume it deals with the active cell though. Usually I would try not to supply a code using select or activate. If you were to supply the code for `GrabDataFromMinutes` maybe a better solution could be found for you.

In the meantime practice with this code, it will select only the non-blank cells in column A and call the `otherMacro`.

```
Sub LoopNonBlanks()
    Dim Lstrw As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Lstrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A2:A" & Lstrw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

    For Each c In Rng.Cells
        c.Select
        otherMacro    'calls the otherMacro
    Next c
End Sub
Sub otherMacro()
    MsgBox "This is the other macro " & ActiveCell.Address & " value is ..." & ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```